# Optimization in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I have the following optimization problem:

[image]

We are minimizing with respect to `y`. A is a known matrix, `b` is a known vector, and `c` is a known constant.

Two important things here: while we are trying to minimize the function, **it can not be less than 0**. Also, it would be ideal to use an R method that doesn't require initial values, since it is quite complex to eyeball a feasible starting value of `y`.

Is there any package/function in R that would allow me to implement this problem?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I second @Stu's suggestion of 'optim'.  Here is an quick example of using it for your case:

```
set.seed(1001)
c = 1
m = 10
b = runif(m)

loss_fun = function(y_i){
  if (all(y_i>=0)){  # <- Here is where we enforce all y's >=0
    return(c - sum(b*log(y_i)))
  }else{
    return(9e9)      # If any y's are negative, return a very large number
  }
}

y_initial = runif(m)

print(optim(y_initial, loss_fun))
```

Hope that helps.

**Update** : Sorry confused your 'Ay' for 'For All y'.  Try something like this:

```
set.seed(1001)
c = 1
m = 10
b = runif(m)
A = matrix(runif(m*m), nrow=m)

loss_fun = function(y_i){
  if (all(A%*%y_i>0)){
    return_val = (c - sum(b*log(y_i)))
  }else{
    return_val = 9e9
  }
  if ((c - sum(b*log(y_i)))<0.000001){
    return_val = 9e9
  }
  else{
    return_val = (c - sum(b*log(y_i)))
  }
  return(return_val)
}

y_initial = runif(m)

print(optim(y_initial, loss_fun, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = 0))
```

You might have to play around with the different methods and bounds on y to get it to act properly.

The overall idea here is to enforce constraints ('if' conditions in your loss function) to by returning large values if they are broken.

**Update 2**: If the function returns the bad value '9e9', it will say it converged because it satisfied the loss function. E.g. every other feasible solution gives a value higher than 9e9.  This means there is no solution for the method/constraints you have.

Comment: Oups I forgot to mention that while we are trying to minimize the objective function, it can not be less than zero... Is there anyway to control for that? I will update my post.

Comment: I also need to impose the constraint `Ay >= 0`

Comment: The positive constraint is not on `y`, but rather on `Ay`, where A is a known matrix, and `>=0` means that each elements of the product of `A` and `y` has to be positive.

Comment: Hah, sorry, confused Ay for 'For All y'.

Comment: No problem :) thank you for adjusting the solution. So, if the $value returned is `9e9`, does that mean that there was no feasible solution?

Comment: Yup, so there are two options.  1- Try playing with the methods. 2- Increase the 9e9 even more.  I forget the integer limits on R, but maybe 9e99? 9e999? etc?

Comment: I increased it to 9e99, but it still returns $value to be 9e99 even though it says `$convergence = 0` (i.e. it found an optimal solution). I am a bit confused...

Comment: Also, I don't know your exact problem, but if the sample space is not 'nice', you might consider a solution like genetic algorithms.  See the R-package 'GA'.

Answer (score 1):

Use `optim`:
**http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html**

This function allows you to optimize a function with constraints using a few different methods.

Check out the examples for a better idea of how your problem can fit into `optim`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The only problem with `optim` is that "feasible" starting values should be provided. It is quite difficult in this case to find feasible starting values (even just as complicated as solving the optimization problem).

Comment: @Mariam for the problem stated you would just start with y=0 as a feasible solution. Are your actual constraints of a different form than those in your question? Not being able to provide a feasible initial starting value is an important constraint, so you should add that to your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case, `y` has to be greater than zero since `log` is involved. I have updated my post with more information.